# changing the query mode through ColdFusion to allow IN instead of equals

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to change some content of the query through ColdFusion. Well I cannot try in query itself because I am getting query from an external source

I have the following query

```
(q.company_na = 'a, b, c, d')
```

and I am trying to convert it to

```
(q.company_na in ('a, b, c, d'))
```

I am using a normal replace but that is not gonna solve the issue. I have seen my try is like this

```
<cfset data = Replace(data,'q.company_na = ','q.company_na IN ','ALL')>
```

but I am missing the opening and closing braces around the IN. How can I approach this?

Comment: Can you be guaranteed of a closing parenthesis after the conditional expression? If so, you can use regular expression matching to match what's inside. You'll also want to break out the string because `= 'a, b, c, d'` and `IN ('a, b, c, d')` are semantically the same.

Comment: is it, let me check something

Comment: no, it is giving an error select * from links where id = '1','2','3','4'

Comment: Notice that you broke the string out. Are you getting `'1, 2, 3, 4'` or `'1', '2', '3', '4'`?

Comment: i tried this too select * from links where id = ('1,2,3,4'), getting error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2,3,4' to data type int.

Comment: Let's backtrack a little and look at the input. Show some samples of input queries. 1) Does the query always have a closing parenthesis after the conditional? 2) What does the right-hand side of the equality operator `=` look like?

Comment: ok, the way is showed, yes it is always like this, it always use that = operator, need to change to IN

Comment: If `id` is an int, then you'll want to use something like: `select * from links where id IN (1,2,3,4)`. If it is a varchar, then something like this: `select * from links where id IN ('1','2','3','4')`. In neither case will `=` work with the right-hand side of the equation.

Answer (score 2):

Another benefit of query parmaters

```
 where q.company_na in (
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" value="a,b,c,d" list="yes">
)
```

Comment: That was my first idea, but the OP has indicated that he's getting the query text externally. This implies that he's using the query object and `cfqueryparam` is not available to him.

Answer (score 0):

Playing a riff off Dan's answer, you can add parameters to the query object.

1. Find all the equality operators in the query.
2. For each equality operator found,

   1. Store the right-hand side into a temporary variable.
   2. Replace the equality operator and the right-hand side with `IN (?)`.
   3. Add a parameter to the query object (`query.addParam(...)`, see [query object documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0693d5dae123bcd28f6d-7ffb.html)) using the value you stored in the temporary variable.

      - Make sure to remove white-space from around the list delimiters.
      - Make sure to set the `list` property of the parameter to `true`.
3. Set the `sql` property of the query object with the modified SQL.

Comment: Hi Paul, I am calling throw coldfusion but i am hitting an asp page, not coldfusion

Comment: The source of the query text doesn't matter if you're manipulating the query and executing it through ColdFusion.

Comment: is it, and if i am passing cfqueryparam to that site who is using asp, will it work,

Comment: Sounds like we're all confused about the requirements. Both answers so far assume that you are executing this query through a datasource to which ColdFusion has access. You indicate with your answer that you are getting query text from an ASP page, modifying it, and sending it back to the ASP site to execute; your ColdFusion instance does not have access to the datasource. Please clarify as best you can.

Comment: Do you want the query executed by .net or cf?

Comment: Paul has corrected it almost, i am doing a cfhttp to the site, so the aite accepts parameters, i am sending some extra params, so the asp query can be modified in such a mannner that it should pick all my passed data and send me back the result set

Comment: Are you expected to provide a query with parameter placeholders and provide values for those parameters via URL variables? Or are you expected to sanitize the values and pass in a complete query with no parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this?

```
<cfset str = "(q.company_na = 'a, b, c, d')" />
<cfset str = REReplace(str, "(,)\s*", "'\1'", "all") />
<cfset str = REReplace(str, "= ('[^)]*)", "IN (\1)") />
```

Output:

```
(q.company_na IN ('a','b','c','d'))
```

If you want your output to be

```
(q.company_na in ('a, b, c, d'))
```

(which I can't imagine you do, since that is semantically the same as using `=` in this instance), then simply omit the second line above and do this:

```
<cfset str = "(q.company_na = 'a, b, c, d')" />
<cfset str = REReplace(str, "= ('[^)]*)", "IN (\1)") />
```